# Dashboard is not loading for user with non-admin role

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-4, dynamics-crm-online, dashboard-designer

When I logged in with the user who has non-admin security role the dashboard is not loading and browser will get hanged. But when I logged in with user who had Admin role its working good. So, whats the issue in this scenario..?

Comment: Now I tried with "System Administrator" role for that User, still its not working.. :(

Answer (score 0):

It seems a security issue. You will have to check the permissions for the role that the non-admin user has and check if there are limitations on the entity that is being displayed in the dashboard.

maybe this link will help you: http://www.dynamicscrmtrickbag.com/2011/07/15/dynamics-crm-2011-charts-and-dashboards-who-can-see-what/

Hope this will be helpfull

EDIT: Maybe another role conflicts with the one of system admin that might also be possible